# Unable to Archive iOS app with watchOS 2 app

Tags: ios, xcode7, alamofire, watchos-2

I am seeing this error when importing Alamofire in a file in my main app target.

```
error: module file was created for incompatible target armv7k-apple-watchos2.0: /Users/joecarey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule
```

The app builds and runs fine.  I am linking the ios and watchOS versions of Alamofire to the corresponding targets.

Anyone having similar issues?